# Not sure how to properly state my conclusion...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

Below, I have a discriminant that is $<0$. I feel like the way I have written it does not express this fact well. I am hoping to have some advice on how to write it more clearly.

\begin{align*}
b^2-4ac &> 0\\
{(pq)}^2-4(p)({pq^2})&>0 \quad \textrm{(Substituting)}\\
p^2q^2-4p^2q^2 &>0\\
p^2q^2&>4p^2q^2 \quad \textrm{(divide both sides by} \ p^2q^2, p,q \ne 0)\\
1&>4
\end{align*}
Since $1 \ngtr 4$, the discriminant $b^2-4ac \ngtr 0$

Comment: What you have looks fine, but I think you can draw a conclusion a bit faster and without the $p,q \neq 0$ requirement by subtraction $p^2q^2-4p^2q^2=-3p^2q^2$. It's an irrelevant quibble though

Comment: That's a good point though - I skipped over that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$b^2-4ac=(pq)^2-4(p)(pq^2)=-3p^2q^2<0$$

since $p,q \neq 0$.

Remark: negation of $<$ should be $\geq$.